# Scala actors, futures and system calls resulting in Thread leaks

Tags: multithreading, scala, memory-leaks, actor, future

I am running a complex software with different actors (scala actors). Some of them have some executions that uses scala futures to avoid locking and keep processing new received messages (simplified code):

```
  def act {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case (code: String) =>
          val codeMatch = future { match_code(code) }
          for (c <- codeMatch)
            yield callback(code)(JSON.parseJSON(c))
      }
    }
  }

  def match_code(code: String) {
     val result = s"my_script.sh $code" !!
  }
```

I noticed looking at `jvisualvm` and Eclipse Debugger that the number of active threads keeps increasing when this system is running. I am afraid I am having some kind of Thread leak, but I can't detect where is the problem.

Here are some screenshots of both finished and live threads (I hided some live threads that are not related to this problem)

**Finished Threads**
[image: Finished Threads]

**Living threads**
[image: Living threads]

**Edit 1:**
In the above graphs example, I run the system with only 3 actors of different classes: Actor1 sends messages to Actor2 that sends message to Actor3

Answer (score 0):

You are using `receive` so each actor will use its own thread, and you don't at least in this example provide any way for actors to terminate.  So you would expect to have one new thread per actor that was ever started.  If that is what you see, then all is working as expected.  If you want to have actors cease running, you will have to let them eventually fall out of the `while` loop or call `sys.exit` on them or somesuch.

(Also, old-style Scala actors are deprecated in favor of Akka actors in 2.11.)

You also don't (in the code above) have any indication whether the future actually completed.  If the futures don't finish, they'll keep tying up threads.

Comment: Ok, it would be an improvement to use `react` instead of receive, but this does not explain why new threads are being created and retained. In the example, I forgot to mention that in this example, I create only 3 actors (of different classes)

Comment: @DanielCukier - Do your futures actually finish running?  In your sample code, I don't see anything that blocks.  How do you know you're not just accumulating more and more of them?

Comment: I am sure they finish running (because there is a return value, and I use it). But debugging I noticed that the thread specific to this future remains blocked on:
Unsafe.park(Boolean, Long) line: not available 
ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue) line: 2075 
ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue) line: 1979 
ForkJoinWorkerThread.run() line: 107

Comment: @DanielCukier - Could be a bug; I don't know.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Do you know the difference between ForkJoinPool-worker threads and pool-x-thread-y threads? Who create these pools?

Comment: @DanielCukier This is the same general issue as your other questions? Somewhere else I distinguished between the threads that are created ad hoc to read process output and the FJP threads for the actors. And that when you managed-block, you grow the FJP. It's probably better to consolidate under one question.

Comment: Which threadpoolExecutor are you using for `future` execution? i.e. from the image what type is `pool2`